# Correct way to write PDO update statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is this the correct way to write a PDO update statement? I based it off a tutorial I saw online but it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all when fired by AJAX (even though the AJAX request is being logged as successful in the console, no update is made to the database):

```
$duedate = $_POST["duedate"];
$status = $_POST["status"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

$sql = "UPDATE pm_schedule SET duedate=?, status=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($duedate,$status,$id));
```

Comment: You're not doing any error checking.  the prepare() method can fail, as can the execute() method (Either by returning FALSE or NULL, or by throwing an exception, depending how you configured PDO).  You need to check that there wasn't an error thrown.

Comment: In case of using exceptions manual checking is not needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, but you need to tell PDO to raise an error on error.
So, make your connection code like this:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

And make sure you can see PHP errors. So, you'll kn ow what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
$duedate = $_POST["duedate"];
$status = $_POST["status"];
$id = $_POST["id"];

try {
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE `pm_schedule` SET `duedate` = ?, `status` = ? WHERE `id` = ?');
    $sql->execute(array($duedate, $status, $id));
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

`PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` This helps you find the error

With the `try` and `catch` you can get an `echo` an error message of where and why it fails.

Comment: Why are you applying htmlspecialchars?  There's no reason why that would fix the problem.

Comment: That's bad practice to wrap every statement in try catch. Do it only if you want to bypass an error. Otherwise it have to be handled by main exception handler. And echoing error message out unconditionally is also bad.

Comment: Could you also explain why and what will happen?

Comment: The problem is that execution will continue after the exception has been caught and handled.  This may be exactly what you want, but in other cases the exception might indicate that something you can't recover from happened.

Answer (score 0):

Here is very good [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) to understand PDO

And correct way is:

```
// Named Placeholders
$sSql  = "UPDATE mytable SET FName = :FName, LName = :LName, Age = :Age, Gender = :Gender WHERE ID = :ID;";

// PDO prepared statement
$oSth = $oDbh->prepare($sSql);

// Bind Named Placeholders
$oSth->bindParam(":FName", $FName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$oSth->bindParam(":LName", $LName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$oSth->bindParam(":Age", $Age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$oSth->bindParam(":Gender", $Gender, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$oSth->bindParam(":ID", $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// Execute PDO with condition
if ($oSth->execute()) {
    // Get Affected row
    $iAffectedRows = $oSth->rowCount();
    $oSth->closeCursor();
    return $iAffectedRows;
} else {
    // PDO error, could also be caught in a try/catch statement
    $errorMsg = $oSth->errorInfo();
    error_log(json_encode($errorMsg));
}
```

Comment: It's way more code than in the OP. Any reason to write all this stuff? PDO is good with "lazy binding" and PHP is good with error handling. No need in rewriting these things manually.

Comment: Nope, it's not necessary to write all stuff here. But, I have written for best understanding to PDO...:)

Comment: You should use `try` and `catch`