# SQL PDO INSERT query not entering values into table

Tags: mysql, pdo

My SQL PDO INSERT query does not appear to be inserting data into the table and does not return any error message stating why it can't do this. Any idea as to what is going on?

**UPDATE:** I'm getting the following error message `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }` after running `var_dump($pdo->errorInfo())`

```
$dept = $_POST['dept'];
$module_id = $_POST['moduleCode'];
$day_id = $_POST['day'];
$period_id = $_POST['period'];
$length_id = $_POST['length'];
$semester = $_POST['semester'];
$round = $_POST['round'];
$group_size = $_POST['group_size'];
$room_structure = $_POST['room_structure'];
$lecture_style = $_POST['lecture_style'];
$roomAllocation = $_POST['roomAllocation'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

// insert request into table

$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_request
                (dept_id,
                module_id,
                day_id,
                period_id,
                length_id,
                semester,
                round,
                group_size,
                room_structure,
                lecture_style,
                park_id,
                allocation
                notes)
                VALUES 
                (:dept,
                :module_id,
                :day_id,
                :period_id,
                :length_id,
                :semester,
                :round,
                :group_size,
                :room_structure,
                :lecture_style,
                :park,
                :allocation
                :notes)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':dept' => $dept, 
                                            ':module_id' => $module_id,
                                            ':day_id' => $day_id,
                                            ':period_id' => $period_id,
                                            ':length_id' => $length_id,
                                            ':semester' => $semester,
                                            ':round' => $round,     
                                            ':group_size' => $group_size,                                                                                                                                                                               
                                            ':room_structure' => $room_structure,                                                                                                                                                                               
                                            ':lecture_style' => $lecture_style, 
                                            ':park' => $park,   
                                            ':allocation' => $roomAllocation,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                            ':notes' => $notes ) );
$request_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

// create allocation

$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_allocation
                (request_id,
                status)
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :status";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':request_id' => $request_id, 
                                            ':status' => $status ) );
$allocation_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

// insert weeks

$weeks = explode(",", $_POST["weeks"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($weeks); $i++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_week
                (request_id,
                allocation_id,
                week)
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :allocation_id,
                :week)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':request_id' => $request_id, 
                                            ':allocation_id' => $allocation_id,
                                            ':week' => $weeks[$i] ) );
}

// insert fac pref

$roomFac = explode(",", $_POST["roomFac"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($roomFac); $i++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_facpref
                (request_id,
                facilities_id)
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :facilities_id)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':request_id' => $request_id, 
                                            ':facilities_id' => $roomFac[$i] ) );
}

// insert room pref

$room_id = explode(",", $_POST["roomPref"]);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($room_id); $i++) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_roompref
                (request_id,
                room_id)
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :room_id)";
$stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
$stm->execute( array( ':request_id' => $request_id, 
                                            ':room_id' => $room_id[$i] ) );
}
var_dump($stm->errorInfo());
```

Comment: errorInfo doesn't help. [You've been told already how to get an error from PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14747978/285587) but for some reason still don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `var_dump($pdo->errorInfo())` AND  `$stm->errorInfo();` after every statement to see what errors PDO gives.

P.s. you have errors in your queries. You miss last bracket:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_allocation
                (request_id,
                status
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :status";
```

and this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ts_facpref
                (request_id,
                facilities_id,
                VALUES 
                (:request_id,
                :facilities_id";
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that! I've made the changes and now get the error message: `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }`

Comment: I get the message `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(176) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('0', 'Any')' at line 4" }`

Comment: You still miss some parenthesis' e.g. "INSERT INTO ts_facpref
                (request_id,
                facilities_id,
                VALUES "

Comment: Now I get `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL } Your booking has been successfully submitted.`

Comment: It seems as if only 0's are being inserted for every value with the lastInsert code and no values are being entered for ts_request

Comment: Then error is in your first query. Aanalyze your POST-variables, and see the $stm -> errorInfo(); etc ..

Answer (score 1):

I can't resist from posting [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php)-based solution.
The only change have to be made is: form field names have to match database column names (i.e. `moduleCode` have to be `module_id` in the form). Having this settled, you can get rid of 90% of your code, making it DRY (stands for Don't Repeat Yourself).
The code for the first insert would be as small as these 4 following lines:

```
$allowed = array(dept_id, module_id, day_id, period_id, length_id, semester, round,
            group_size, room_structure, lecture_style, park_id, allocation, notes);
$data = $db->filterArray($allowed, $_POST);
$db->query("INSERT INTO ts_request SET ?u", $data);
```

Needless to say that to spot the error in such a small code is much easier than in a larger one.
Also, letting PHP to build the query for you will help you avoid such sad mistakes like absent comma between `allocation` and `notes` in your manually created query or reserved word collision or whatever else